# Problema de iniciar sesion en php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

como va?

Tengo un problema en el inicio de sesión con la app en php que hice
No entiendo donde tengo el problema, el compilador no dice nada.
Paso los codigos relacionados que tengo

Clase Auth.php:

```
class Auth {
    private $db;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->db = Database::getInstance()->getConnection();
    }

    public function iniciarSesion($username, $password) {
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE username = :username");
        $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
        $stmt->execute();

        $usuario = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if ($usuario && password_verify($password, $usuario['password'])) {
            // La contraseña es correcta. Inicia la sesión y guarda los datos del usuario en la sesión.
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
            return true;
        } else {
            // El nombre de usuario o la contraseña
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Login.php

```
<?php
include_once 'config.php';
include_once 'auth.php';

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $username = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['username']));
    $password = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['password']));
    
    if ($auth->iniciarSesion($username, $password)) {
        header("Location: opciones.php");
        exit();
    } else {
        $error_message = "Usuario o contraseña incorrectos";
    }
}
?>
```

Por mas que coloque los datos bien que tengo almacenados en la BD me da el $error_message

Probe la conexion con la BD y es satisfactoria.

Adjunto captura de los datos almacenados en la BD con sus tablas y columnas de los usuarios
[image: MySQL]

Les agradezco si me dan una mano.

Alguna ayuda o solucion

Answer (score 0):

Es importante preservar los nombres de los archivos. En Windows los nombres son insensibles a las mayúsculas, pero si mueves esa app a un MacOS, o a un Linux (la mayoría de los hostings son Linux) van a salir muchos errores. Por ejemplo, pones que el archivo se llama `Auth.php` pero haces un include a `auth.php`.

Por otro lado, a menos que tengas un [autoloader](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+autoloader) que requiera a `auth.php` y a `login.php` (cosa que me parece raro ya que en `login.php` se hace un `include_once 'auth.php';`), entonces el problema puede ser porque no has creado el objeto de autenticación en `login.php`.

```php
<?php
include_once 'config.php';
include_once 'auth.php';

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $username = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['username']));
    $password = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['password']));
    
    $auth = new Auth(); // <-- *** Crear el objeto auth
    if ($auth->iniciarSesion($username, $password)) {
        header("Location: opciones.php");
        exit();
    } else {
        $error_message = "Usuario o contraseña incorrectos";
    }
}
```

Finalmente, en el archivo `auth.php`, [password_verify](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.password-verify.php) compara una cadena (entrada del usuario) contra un *hash* en la base de datos. Según la captura de pantalla que pones, las claves están en texto plano, por lo que siempre va a retornar `false`. Para que funcione, en la columna `password` deben haber *hashes* creados con [password_hash](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.password-hash.php)

Comment: Estimado, buenas tardes
Desde ya muchas gracias por la ayuda.
Con respecto a la sensibilidad de las mayusculas, fue equivocacion mia al generar este post, en el directorio raiz se llama auth.php, disculpe por la equivocacion.
Voy a probar las opciones que me dio de generar el objeto de autenticacion en login.php y editar la tabla de MySQL con el pasword hash.
Para vuestra informacion, proble en la autenticacion del logueo sin el password verify y me saltaba el mismo error. y por otro lado no me da ningun error en la consola ni en el depurador.
Desde ya muchas gracias
Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

El problema era que estaba generando el usuario desde MySQL
La solucion fue generar un register.php y en el momento de registro, hashear la pass y ahi me tomaba el pasword verify
muchas gracias aeportugar
Saludos.